# Writing a custom manager for my model class with an existing obj instance

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am reading on how to write a custom manager for my model however it seems like I have a few questions. The reason I would like to add a custom manager to my class is because I would like to introduce a method called "customUpdate" which would basically check if the members in a dict are members of this class. This is what my code looks like so far.Then Ill post in some questions that I have

```
class modelEmployer(models.Model):
    user                = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    location            = models.PointField(srid=4326,max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)  
    objects             = GeoManager()  # models.GeoManager()
```

Now this is what my manager class would like this is a rough sketch:

```
class customEmployerManager(models.Manager):

    def customUpdate(dataDict):
        # Check if the fields in this data are present in this model
        for key in dataDict:
            empInst = How do I get instance of class which filter returned ?
            if not hasattr(empInst, key):
                # This property is not present
                dataDict.pop(key)
                empInst.update(**dataDict) #Will this work ? Update only works with queryset
```

Now here are my questions
1- From the tutorials that I read I need to add `customEmployerManager` to my main model class as an object member like this `objects = customEmployerManager()` however I am currently using geodjango and I already have something there how do I add another `customEmployerManager` there ?

2-I would like my update method to be called when I do something like this

```
modelEmployer.objects.filter(....).customUpdate(xx)
```

In customUpdate how do I access the queryset so I can call `.update(**dataDict)` on it ? I am currently doing `empInst.update(**dataDict)` which will not work ? Also how do I get the instance of modelEmployer instance on which update is being called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override [GeoManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/) like this:

```
class customEmployerManager(GeoManager):

  def customUpdate(self, **dataDict):
    # Check if the fields in this data are present in this model
    empInst = self.get_queryset()
    for i in empInst:
        i.update(**dataDict)

# in models.py
class modelEmployer(models.Model):
    objects = customEmployerManager()
    ...
    def update(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
           if hasattr(self, key):
              setattr(self, key, value) 
        self.save()
```

You need to call the manager like this:

```
 modelEmployer.objects.customUpdate(**dict)
```

Comment: how do I integrate `customEmployerManager` to `modelEmployer` ?

Comment: isnt customUpdate supposed to have self as 1st parameter ?

Comment: I tried the following  `modelEmployee.custom_manager.filter(id=portfolio.employee.id).customUpdate(**dict)` however I get the error `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'customUpdate'`

Comment: I am not sure, can you try to run migrations, and see if it works. Else can you also try the second solution if first one did not work.